# Where to view Google Analytics "Track clicks on outbound links" results?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Drupal's Google Analytics module 8.x-2.5. The module configuration has a check box for "Track clicks on outbound links", which I checked since the module was installed. However, I don't see outbound link stats in Google Analytics - am I missing something? Is there something else that needs to be done for setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module tracks outbound links via GA event tracking. It will send a [click action](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/google_analytics/-/blob/d1b36c559435af2d16d37c7358844dffc67623e9/js/google_analytics.js#L65) to GA under the **Outbound links** category. The metrics for this event category can be found in the **Behavior > Events** menu in the GA interface.

Comment: Thank you, there it was the whole time!